# "Missing issuer google_id_token" when generating OpenApi doc for Cloud Endpoints with Auth0

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm creating an app backend with GAE Standard Environment and Cloud Endpoints in Python that needs to be able to authenticate via Auth0.

I have included an "issuers" object in the API decorator (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/authenticating-users#authenticating_with_auth0).

I have also set up an Auth0 account and have set up a "Regular Web Application" that is referenced in the issuers object and have included the following libraries in my project directory: google-endpoints 4.4.0 and google-endpoints-api-management 1.9.1

**When I attempt to generate the OpenApi document (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/adding-api-management), I get the following error: "TypeError: Missing issuer google_id_token".**

**Any advice as to how to properly generate an OpenApi document for Cloud Endpoints in Python that incorporates Auth0?**

Answer (score 0):

You have passed a list or tuple for `audiences` somewhere in your code. When you do this, Endpoints assumes there will be an issuer named `google_id_token`. (This is for backwards compatibility reasons.) If you wish to use issuers with other names, you need to pass a dict as `audiences`; for example: `audiences={"auth0": ["aud-1.auth0.com", "aud-2.auth0.com"]}`.